# NHibernate: An association from the table X refers to an unmapped class: X

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two mapping files for an order and a customer object.

Customer Mapping:

```
  <class name="OODB.Domain.Customer, OODB.Domain" entity-name="Customers">
     <id name="ID" column="customer_id">
      <generator class="guid" />
     </id>
     <property name="FirstName" column="first_name"/>
     <property name="LastName" column="last_name"/>
     <property name="EMail" column="email"/>
     <property name="Telephone" column="telephone" />

    <component name="Address" class="Address">
       <property name="Street" column="street"></property>
       <property name="PostalCode" column="postal_code"></property>
       <property name="City" column="city"></property>
    </component>
  </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Order Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="OODB.Domain"   namespace="OODB.Domain">  
  <class name="OODB.Domain.CustomerOrder, OODB.Domain" entity-name="Orders">
    <id name="ID" column="order_id">
      <generator class="guid"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="OrderNo" column="order_no" length="8" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="Status" column="status" not-null="true"></property>
    <many-to-one name="Orderer" class="Customer" column="customer_id" insert="true" not-found="exception" fetch="join"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Customer class:

```
namespace OODB.Domain
{
    public class Customer : ModelBase<Customer>
    {
        public virtual string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual string EMail
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual string Telephone
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public virtual Address Address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

...
}
```

Customer Order class:

```
public class CustomerOrder : ModelBase<CustomerOrder>
{
    public virtual string OrderNo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Customer Orderer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual OrderStatus Status
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
...
}
```

Everything works great, if I remove the many-to-one stuff (Mappings are integrated as an embedded resource. I've checked this twice.). Otherwise I get the error 'An association from the table Orders refers to an unmapped class: OODB.Domain.Customer'. But the Customer object is mapped... What I am missing?

Comment: Maybe show us the actual class definition of the "CustomerOrder" class. Specifically, the "Orderer" property.

Comment: Another thing to test: Have you set "BuildAction" on "Customer.hbm.xml" to "EmbeddedResource"? (It's a simple thing which has caught me up in the past)

Comment: Did you managed to fetch Customer objects by themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mixed up the table and entity-name attribute on the class element. :\

Comment: You should look into Fluent nHibernate. It provides a much less error-prone way of defining the mappings.

Comment: I needed to set it as an embedded resource in the properties build action of the .hbm file

Answer (score 4):

My guess for your example: The "class" specification in the `many-to-one` element must have the same level of detail as every other `class` specification. Particularly, you must include the assembly.

```
<many-to-one name="Orderer" class="OODB.Domain.Customer, OODB.Domain" column="customer_id" insert="true" not-found="exception" fetch="join"/>
```

Comment: Did you make the same adjustment to the Address class in the Customer mapping's?

Answer (score 1):

A possible source of this exception is not having the .html file be an "Embedded Resource".  If the mapping file (hbm) is not in the right directory, this exception.  If you look at the output window, you'll see something like:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration: ERROR lambda_method - An association from the table
SubsequentReportDetail refers to an unmapped class: NS.Project.Data.Domain.Class
NHibernate.MappingException: An association from the table X refers to an 
unmapped class:  NS.Project.Data.Domain.Class
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue for me was.. same property mapped twice

```
   Property(x => x.MyProperty);
   Bag(x => x.MyProperty, colmap => { }, map => map.OneToMany(x => { }));
```